# I'm having trouble with laying out my page using CSS flex-box and CSS grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

1. I'm making this checkers game using HTML and CSS[**css flexbox** and **css grid**] (just layout, for now, no logics yet). The layout is complete and everything looks great except that **the page is not responsive VERTICALLY**. When I reduce the browser size(Chrome) vertically, the checkers board (which is wrapped in a container) gets out of its container (a container that is also wrapped in a `section`) and overlaps all the way to the `nav` and also out of the `section`. You can clearly see it when you preview the code snippet. **PS: on full vieport height it looks just fine** It messes up on reduced browser height.
2. Also, let me ask how to layout the page is such a way that the `nav` takes like 20% of the viewport height and the `section` taking the remaining part of the viewport. See in my code how I did it and give me a better way to do it because what i did didn't work out.

**Edit: What I actually need is that I want the chessboard to somehow be locked inside its parent(in my scenario, its a section) in such a way that when resizing the viewport height of the browser it should remain contained inside its parent and not go out of its parent and overlap other sections(in this case, the nav).
You see twitter? try reducing the browser height to absolutely zero you'll see the contents/elements of the page don't get affected rather the browser just wraps or covers them up(no twitter elements get distorted). That's what I want**

```css
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
}


/* THE NAV */

nav {
    background: black;
    height: 20vh;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}


/* SECTION */

section {
    background: pink;
    height: 80vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Architects Daughter', cursive;
    font-size: 3rem;
}


/* setting up the board */

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
}

.zone-1 {
    background: #CEB67B;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}

.zone-2 {
    background: #735131;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}


/* Checkers */

.checkers-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.home-checkers {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: red;
    border: 3px solid white;
}

.away-checkers {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 3px solid white;
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Grid Checkers</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="gridDraft.css" />

    <!-- fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Architects+Daughter&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <h1>Checkers Game</h1>
    </nav>
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Home Section -->

            <!-- row-1 -->
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="home-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="home-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="home-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="home-checkers"></div>
            </div>

            <!-- row-2 -->
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="home-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="home-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="home-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="home-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>

            <!-- row-3 -->
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="home-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="home-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="home-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="home-checkers"></div>
            </div>

            <!-- Empty rows start here -->

            <!-- row-4 -->
            <div class="zone-2"></div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2"></div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2"></div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2"></div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>

            <!-- row-5 -->
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2"></div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2"></div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2"></div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2"></div>

            <!-- Empty rows end here -->

            <!-- Away Section -->

            <!-- row-6 -->
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="away-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="away-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="away-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="away-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <!-- row-7 -->
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="away-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="away-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="away-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="away-checkers"></div>
            </div>

            <!-- row-8 -->
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="away-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="away-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="away-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="away-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://web-design-weekly.com/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/ might be an hint if https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries is not ;)  pen to play with about `vmin` https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/OJMjmNN

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the board squares responsive to the screen height

`width: calc(80vh / 8); height: calc(80vh / 8);` instead of `width: 60px; height: 60px;`.

We have 80vh to play with and 8 squares that stack verticaly. So for the hight you can run a `height: calc(80vh / 8);` to find that size. Then you make the width of each square the same as the height `width: calc(80vh / 8);`.

```css
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
}


/* THE NAV */

nav {
    background: black;
    height: 20vh;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}


/* SECTION */

section {
    background: pink;
    height: 80vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Architects Daughter', cursive;
    font-size: 3rem;
}


/* setting up the board */

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
}

.zone-1 {
    background: #CEB67B;
    width: calc(80vh / 8);
    height: calc(80vh / 8);
}

.zone-2 {
    background: #735131;
    width: calc(80vh / 8);
    height: calc(80vh / 8);
}


/* Checkers */

.checkers-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.home-checkers {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: red;
    border: 3px solid white;
}

.away-checkers {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 3px solid white;
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Grid Checkers</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="gridDraft.css" />

    <!-- fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Architects+Daughter&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <h1>Checkers Game</h1>
    </nav>
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Home Section -->

            <!-- row-1 -->
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="home-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="home-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="home-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="home-checkers"></div>
            </div>

            <!-- row-2 -->
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="home-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="home-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="home-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="home-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>

            <!-- row-3 -->
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="home-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="home-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="home-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="home-checkers"></div>
            </div>

            <!-- Empty rows start here -->

            <!-- row-4 -->
            <div class="zone-2"></div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2"></div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2"></div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2"></div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>

            <!-- row-5 -->
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2"></div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2"></div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2"></div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2"></div>

            <!-- Empty rows end here -->

            <!-- Away Section -->

            <!-- row-6 -->
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="away-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="away-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="away-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="away-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <!-- row-7 -->
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="away-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="away-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="away-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="away-checkers"></div>
            </div>

            <!-- row-8 -->
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="away-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="away-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="away-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
            <div class="zone-2 checkers-container">
                <div class="away-checkers"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zone-1"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution but this has somehow changed my layout. The chessboard now is like attached to the edges of the section especially top. when I put some margin it only adds an extra space  at the bottom. Its like it pushes the section away from the viewport.. Isnt there just a way to like lock my chessboard so that it doesn't go out of its boundaries on resizing(esp vertically) @AdamBraid

Comment: And i have noticed that with your contribution, when the the screen become small...the chessboard messes up..try running the code and just view the preview and not the full screen